# How do I get geo coordinates out of the JSON? Twitter API

Tags: jquery, json, multidimensional-array, twitter

This is what the JSON outputs

```
{
  "created_at": "Wed, 09 May 2012 22:13:32 +0000",
  "from_user": "EastCClothing",
  "from_user_id": 119699125,
  "from_user_id_str": "119699125",
  "from_user_name": "Tester23",
  "geo": {
    "coordinates": [
      54.9742,
      -1.5974
    ],
    "type": "Point"
  },
  "id": 200347799861198850,
  "id_str": "200347799861198849",
  "iso_language_code": "pt",
  "metadata": {
    "result_type": "recent"
  },
  "profile_image_url": "http://a0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png",
  "profile_image_url_https": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_0_normal.png",
  "source": "&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/download/android&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow&quot;&gt;Twitter for Android&lt;/a&gt;",
  "text": "#CM0655 GEO",
  "to_user": null,
  "to_user_id": 0,
  "to_user_id_str": "0",
  "to_user_name": null
},
```

What I am trying to do is get a hold of the coordinates so that I may use them with google maps api, I am able to access all the other details fine but can't access the coordinates through what I expected 'json.results[i].geo.coordinates'. Here's my JQuery

```
$(function(){
    function searchTweets() {
        var url='http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=cm0655';
        $.getJSON(url,function(json){


            var output = [];


            for (var i = 0, len = json.results.length; i < len; i++) {


               output.push('<p id="tweet"><img id="tweetImage" src="' + json.results[i].profile_image_url + '" width="48" height="48" /><span id="tweetText">' + '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + json.results[i].from_user + '">' + json.results[i].from_user + "</a> " + json.results[i].text + "<br />" + json.results[i].created_at + '</p>' + json.results[i].geo.coordinates + '</span>');
            }

            $("div.twitter2").html(output.join('')).slideDown('slow');
        });
    }


    var timer = setInterval(searchTweets, 20000);


    searchTweets();

});
```

Many thanks

Comment: can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: no error, just wont display anything when I try
'json.results[i].geo.coordinates'

and when I try
'json.results[i].geo'

it displays [object Object]

Comment: I edited my answer to potentially help you debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the previous fail i've found a solution what you need to do is check if the results.geo is an object then loop if not exclude it or set it to something else i've done this

Disclaimer This is very much so not the best solution but it is a working one to give you an idea of how to solve the issue. Hope it helps!

```
$(function() {
    function searchTweets() {
        var url = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?callback=?&q=from:Eastcclothing';
        $.getJSON(url, function(json) {

            console.log(json);
            var output = [];


            for (var i = 0, len = json.results.length; i < len; i++) {

                if ($.isPlainObject(json.results[i].geo)) {
                    output.push('<p id="tweet"><img id="tweetImage" src="' + json.results[i].profile_image_url + '" width="48" height="48" /><span id="tweetText">' + '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + json.results[i].from_user + '">' + json.results[i].from_user + "</a> " + json.results[i].text + "<br />" + json.results[i].created_at + '</p>' + json.results[i].geo.coordinates + '</span>');
                } else {
                    output.push('<p id="tweet"><img id="tweetImage" src="' + json.results[i].profile_image_url + '" width="48" height="48" /><span id="tweetText">' + '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + json.results[i].from_user + '">' + json.results[i].from_user + "</a> " + json.results[i].text + "<br />" + json.results[i].created_at + '</p>' + json.results[i].geo + '</span>');
                }
            }

            $("div.twitter2").html(output.join('')).slideDown('slow');
        });
    }


    var timer = setInterval(searchTweets, 20000);


    searchTweets();

});​
```

also to help heres a working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/th3fallen/jc2Kf/

Comment: Maybe you can help me further, how would I then get place the coordinations into a variable to be used elsewhere?

Comment: Would you want each location in its own variable or just a single one?

Comment: well I would need a location for each tweet so they could then be placed on a map? thankyou

Comment: you could try this http://jsfiddle.net/th3fallen/jc2Kf/2/  which will create an object called location with an array of all the id's with the coordinates inside theres a console.log at the bottom you may want to remove i just added it for debugging on my end.

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd add the $.each method just in case anyone went down that path.

```
    // The code below uses the Twitter API found here https://dev.twitter.com/docs to search for the latest mention of CM0655 (module code).

    var twitterURL = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23CM0655";
    function twitterSearch() { // Create the weather function   
        $.ajax({
        url: twitterURL, //http request string for the weather service
        dataType: "jsonp",                                                                                                  
        success: function(JSON) {                      // If successful parse the JSON data
            $('#twitterSearch').html("");
            $.each(JSON.results, function(i,tweet){
                    var tweeterID  = tweet.from_user_id;
                    var dateFormat = tweet.created_at;
                    var newDate    = dateFormat.replace('+0000', '');
                    var title      = 'title="Tweeted from"';
                    var id         = tweet.id;
                    var locData    = tweet.geo;
                    getCordsData(locData);
                    $('#twitterSearch').append('<li id="tweet' + id + '" class="mainP tweet"><img class="tweetImage" src="'+ tweet.profile_image_url +'" height="20" width="20" /> <a class="tweetLink" href="http://twitter.com/' + tweet.from_user + '" target="_blank">' + tweet.from_user + '</a> on the ' + newDate + ' <br /> tweeted<span id="tweetTextColor">: ' + tweet.text + '</span></li>');
            });
        //alert("Ajax text");
        setTimeout(twitterSearch, 10000);
        }
        }); // End of ajax
     } // End of function

    function getCordsData(data){
        if(data == null){
            data = "No location data found!";
            alert(data);
        }else{
            var long = data['coordinates'][0];
            var lat = data['coordinates'][1];
            alert("long:" + long + "Lat:" + lat);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting an issue because you are trying to concatenate an array with a string, what you may need to do is this:

```
...+"["+json.results[i].geo.coordinates[0]+","+json.results[i].geo.coordinates[1]+"]"+...
```

rather than just

```
...+json.results[i].geo.coordinates+...
```

---

or try this:

```
if (json.results[i].geo) console.log('<p id="tweet"><img id="tweetImage" src="' + json.results[i].profile_image_url + '" width="48" height="48" /><span id="tweetText">' + '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + json.results[i].from_user + '">' + json.results[i].from_user + "</a> " + json.results[i].text + "<br />" + json.results[i].created_at + '</p>' + "["+json.results[i].geo.coordinates[0]+","+json.results[i].geo.coordinates[1]+"]" + '</span>');
```

or even:

```
if (json.results[i].geo) console.log($('<p id="tweet"><img id="tweetImage" src="' + json.results[i].profile_image_url + '" width="48" height="48" /><span id="tweetText">' + '<a href="http://twitter.com/' + json.results[i].from_user + '">' + json.results[i].from_user + "</a> " + json.results[i].text + "<br />" + json.results[i].created_at + '</p>' + "["+json.results[i].geo.coordinates[0]+","+json.results[i].geo.coordinates[1]+"]" + '</span>'));
```

and make sure the html looks correct.

The other problem that i noticed is that you are closing your `</span>` tag before your `</p>` tag, which is not valid html. I dont think that is your problem (it might be?), but you should probably fix it.

Comment: not sure what console.log is supposed to do but it removes all output, still getting nothing from either of the 2 snippets. I appreciate your assitance though, any more ideas?

I rearranged the HTML but as expected that did nothing for the functionality

Comment: console.log will print out the text in the browser's console. In your browser, if you click View -> Deveoper -> JavaScript Console, and then run your code again, it should print out the text in the console.

Comment: The only thing that comes back is a list of    [19:03:04.392] json.results[i].geo is null @ http://localhost/halesports2/content/test.html:43   but nost of the tweets geo.coordinates are 'null' I want to get the coordinates of the ones that aren't

Comment: I edited my answer again, take the two lines that begin with `if (json...` and put them both right above your `output.push(...` line, check the console, and verify that the text printed out, and the html object being created is what you are expecting.

Comment: I've made the edits you suggested, nothing gets output in the console. Please advise?